# Android download file from PHP server

Tags: php, android

I am trying to download a file from my PHP server. Here is my PHP code:

```
$file = 'androidApps/app.apk';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);

exit;
```

File name and file size are correct.
When I use my browser (on my computer AND on my phone) everything is fine. The file is correctly downloaded.

When I try to download it from my android app it will download a 38-byte file.
Still in my android app if I use the direct link to my file it will download it correctly.
Here is my android code:

```
    String path ="http://myserverURLAndPhpFileUrl.php";//If I put the path of my file it will download it correctly
    String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
    URL u = null;

    u = new URL(path);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.connect();

    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

    File file = new File(PATH);
    file.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len1 = 0;
    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        System.out.println(len1);
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();`
```

I have also tried to use the DownloadManager but I get the same issue:

```
  String path = "http://myserverURLAndPhpFileUrl.php";
   UpdateService.this.getSystemService(UpdateService.this.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request dlrequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(path));

    dlrequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);


dlrequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
    dlrequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(UpdateService.this, null, "app.apk");
    System.out.println("FILE dir: " + getExternalFilesDir(null));
    //nqueue this request e
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) UpdateService.this.getSystemService(UpdateService.this.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    long downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(dlrequest);
    downloadManager.enqueue(dlrequest);
```

I am using this code in a service.
I have tested on android 5.0.1 and Android 4.3

PHP version: 5.4.45-0+deb7u8

How can I manage to download my file without using the path of the file ?

Thanks

Comment: You use a wrong url. There is no host in it.

Comment: `final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();`. Remove that line. Its confusing.

Comment: Use the full url to your php script.

Comment: I didn't write the full url here on stackoverflow but I use the correct one in my app

Comment: You could post a better fake url then you did now. You see how confusing it worked now.

Comment: And what is the content of those 38 bytes?

Comment: Thank you @greenapps. i didn't consider reading this file because it has an apk extension... My problem doesn't come from this code but from the way i keep my session in my android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is fine. I just had to add cookies in my request:

```
 dlrequest.addRequestHeader("Cookie","PHPSESSID="+session);
```