# Android download file from Google drive with DownloadManager

Tags: android

I'm using an android application to download a zipped file from my Google Drive account. The file loads 5MB but the emulator only downloads 65KB.
According to this discussion ([Android download file from PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046997/android-download-file-from-php-server)) , this is a Cookie problem but I did not know how to add cookies.
here is my code.
Thank you.

```
void download(String url) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "doc.zip");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
```